# Orbeon and liferay

Tags: jboss, liferay, orbeon

I have downloaded Orbeon version 4.10. I went through the files in the war file and found that it is configured to be a liferay portlet. I'm using Jboss AS 7.1 "Brontes" without Liferay. Is it possible to use Orbeon without liferay and not as a portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Orbeon Forms within Liferay is purely optional and most users do not use it within Liferay. For reference here is a link to the [installation documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped.